# Real world usage of two way generators in javascript

Tags: javascript

Coming from C# world, I am curious to understand what are some of the practical usage of two way generators in javascript. I can understand how generators can be useful in general, but not when it comes to two way generators. Can we use it with RxJS or likes? Can you explain any pattern/scenario where this can be used?

```
function* interrogate() {
   let name = yield "What is your name?";
   let color = yield "What is your favorite color?";
   return `${name}'s favorite color is ${color}.`;
}

let it = interrogate();
it.next();         // { value: "What is your name?", done: false }
it.next('Ethan');  // { value: "What is your favorite color?", done: false }
it.next('orange'); // { value: "Ethan's favorite color is orange.", done:true }
```

Comment: Isn't your example just that?

Comment: @Xotic750 I'd never code anything like that to print a line :), thus I am trying to understand the use case or pattern where two way generators are far better suited than any other mechanism.

Comment: In my understand, it mostly used for handling the async issue and combined with Promises. You can search more bout it using the keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

David Walsh has a [blog about ES6 Generators](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators)

He has an example

```
function *foo(x) {
    var y = 2 * (yield (x + 1));
    var z = yield (y / 3);
    return (x + y + z);
}

var it = foo( 5 );

// note: not sending anything into `next()` here
console.log( it.next() );       // { value:6, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 12 ) );   // { value:8, done:false }
console.log( it.next( 13 ) );   // { value:42, done:true }
```

But again, the use case is as manufactured as your example.

In his summary he says

> It's natural to wonder what this new exotic toy is going to do
>   practically for your code. There's a lot more to them, though. We've
>   just scratched the surface. So we have to dive deeper before we can
>   discover just how powerful they can/will be.
>
> - How does error handling work?
> - Can one generator call another generator?
> - How does async coding work with generators?
>
> Those questions, and more, will be covered in subsequent articles
>   here, so stay tuned!

[In a later blog](https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators) he has the following snippet (and some others)

```
// run (async) a generator to completion
// Note: simplified approach: no error handling here
function runGenerator(g) {
    var it = g(), ret;

    // asynchronously iterate over generator
    (function iterate(val){
        ret = it.next( val );

        if (!ret.done) {
            // poor man's "is it a promise?" test
            if ("then" in ret.value) {
                // wait on the promise
                ret.value.then( iterate );
            }
            // immediate value: just send right back in
            else {
                // avoid synchronous recursion
                setTimeout( function(){
                    iterate( ret.value );
                }, 0 );
            }
        }
    })();
}

runGenerator( function *main(){
    var result1 = yield request( "http://some.url.1" );
    var data = JSON.parse( result1 );

    var result2 = yield request( "http://some.url.2?id=" + data.id );
    var resp = JSON.parse( result2 );
    console.log( "The value you asked for: " + resp.value );
} );
```

Which seems a bit more real world.

He summarises

> Put simply: a generator + yielded promise(s) combines the best of both
>   worlds to get really powerful and elegant sync(-looking) async flow
>   control expression capabilities. With simple wrapper utilities (which
>   many libraries are already providing), we can automatically run our
>   generators to completion, including sane and sync(-looking) error
>   handling!

Comment: This answer is rather obsolete after async/await.